# Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, integration-testing, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to create an Integration Test. For this I want a clean database. I also have a Database Project which contains the tables and scripts that would give me a clean installation.

As such, I have tried to build this with Microsoft.Build framework. Here is the code:

```
var props = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "UpdateDatabase", "True" },
    { "PublishScriptFileName", "schema-update.sql" },
    { "SqlPublishProfilePath", "../../../../MyProj.Database/MyProj.Database.publish.xml" }
};

//The relative path starts in the bin folder so I have to go back a few.
var projectPath = "../../../../MyProj.Database/MyProj.Database.sqlproj";

var result = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(
    new BuildParameters{ Loggers = new [] { new ConsoleLogger() }}, 
    new BuildRequestData(new ProjectInstance(projectPath, props, null), new [] { "Publish" } )
);

return result.OverallResult == BuildResultCode.Success;
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

> The imported project \"C:\Users\Me\.nuget\packages\microsoft.testplatform.testhost\15.8.0\lib\netstandard1.5\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets\" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\_websites\Projects\MyProj\MyProj.Database\MyProj.Database.sqlproj

Now the first path doesn't exist. There is is indeed the `netstandard1.5` folder, but no `Microsoft` folder under it. The second path, the one to my project does exist and what it lists there is correct. If I copy and past the path, I get to my project.

Also, if I manually publish the database project, there are no problems.

I'm wondering if there is maybe a package I'm missing to make this work? I have `Microsoft.Build` and `Microsoft.Build.Framework` installed.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error message trying to build in TFS.

```
2019-07-15T12:29:03.3583684Z C:\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.136.1\_work\4\s\Database\ccc.SqlServer.Database\ccc.SqlServer.Database.sqlproj(126,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.136.1\_work\_tool\dncs\2.2.203\x64\sdk\2.2.203\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
2019-07-15T12:29:03.9586915Z 
2019-07-15T12:29:03.9588040Z Build FAILED.
2019-07-15T12:29:03.9605507Z 
2019-07-15T12:29:03.9611553Z C:\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.136.1\_work\4\s\Database\ccc.SqlServer.Database\ccc.SqlServer.Database.sqlproj(126,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.136.1\_work\_tool\dncs\2.2.203\x64\sdk\2.2.203\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
2019-07-15T12:29:03.9612755Z     0 Warning(s)
2019-07-15T12:29:03.9613175Z     1 Error(s)
2019-07-15T12:29:03.9625235Z 
2019-07-15T12:29:03.9630668Z Time Elapsed 00:00:04.67
2019-07-15T12:29:04.0221095Z ##[error]Error: C:\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.136.1\_work\_tool\dncs\2.2.203\x64\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 1
```

My problem ended up being user error.

The TFS build definition was setup to only build `*.csproj` files. However, one of the C# projects had an unnecessary dependency on a `.sqlproj` project. Removing the dependency allowed the build to succeed.

(I think if we were trying to build `.sqlproj` files then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205151/1462295) would be useful, outlining that the SQL Server Data Tools need to be installed on all build agents.)